# Update a default value only during design-time

Tags: delphi, components

I would like to update the default value of a private variable linked to a public property only during design-time, in case it's possible.

```
TMyComp = class(TComponent)
  private
    FColumnWidth: Integer;
    FColumnWidthDef: Integer;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property ColumnWidth: Integer read FColumnWidth write SetColumnWidth  default 50;
  end;

...

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  FColumnWidth:= 50;
  FColumnWidthDef:= FColumnWidth;
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FColumnWidth:= 0;
  FColumnWidthDef:= 0;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SetColumnWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
if FColumnWidth <> Value then
  begin
    FColumnWidth:= Value;

    FColumnWidthDef:= FColumnWidth; //<-- how to run this only during design-time?
  end;
end;
```

What I would like to do is to store in a private variable the default value for the property `ColumnWidth`. Inside of run-time code of the component there is a reset button that should change the property to default value `FColumnWidthDef`. If I do it like the code from above, this value will be updated in design-time and also in run-time.

Answer (score 3):

```
procedure TMyComponent.SetColumnWidth(const Value: Integer);
begin
if FColumnWidth <> Value then
  begin
    FColumnWidth:= Value;
    if csDesigning in ComponentState then
      FColumnWidthDef:= FColumnWidth;  
  end;
end;
```

but this do not go to dfm file and when you run app your def will be gone
why not to put this as another published property?
or better write "stored" function like it is done many times in delphi source code like this

```
property BorderIcons: TBorderIcons read FBorderIcons write SetBorderIcons stored IsForm
      default [biSystemMenu, biMinimize, biMaximize];
```

Comment: The problem with published property is it got visible in Object Inspector. Or maybe not, maybe he would like to see it there, if it would be read-only property. So, he has to either make it a property and then hide it from OI (fir example by registering nil-editor for it) or he would have to make "virtual property" by overriding `DefineProperties` call as shown at http://www.temporaldoorway.com/programming/cbuilder/advancedissue/aggregatescrollablepanel.htm

Comment: It doesn't need to go to the dfm file. Just check for `csLoading` in the property setter as well as `csDesigning`, and the "default" value will be updated once.